# Only take the last UDP packet of a socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, packet

I'm writing a udp server for a drone. The drone is periodically sending packets about its sensor data. I was wondering if there's a function or an elegant solution to take the last packet to arrive and discard the earlier ones. Right now, calling recv() with the MSG_DONTWAIT flag a bunch of time until it gives EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK error is the only thing I can think of. This seems slow and wasteful.

Comment: Read and discard all but the last datagram. (How do you know what the last one is?)

Comment: @Shawn That's what they are doing. (And they even described how they know it's the last queued packet.) They're asking for an alternative that's "less wasteful".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OS doesn't have a function to get rid of all queued packets but the last. This is not something one normally does. /// The approach you describe is perfectly fine. And hardly wasteful as you claim.

Comment: Use `select()/poll()/epoll()` to tell you when there is data, which gives you the required blocking behaviour and doesn't smoke the CPU, and *then* do your read loop with MSG_DONTWAIT.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the OS doesn't have a function to get rid of all queued packets but the last. This is not something one normally does

The approach you describe is perfectly fine. And hardly wasteful as you claim.

What might be wasteful is how you wait for a packet to arrive when there are none to receive. You should be using `select`/`poll`/`epoll` for this instead of polling, using the loop you describe only once notified that a packet is waiting.

What might be also wasteful is what you do between checking for new packets. You're worried about micro- or nanoseconds of CPU power when you apparently spend more time processing the packets than the push period of the drone? If you are in need of optimization, that's where you should start.

Note that you don't want to keep the last packet returned by `recv`, but the packet with the latest time stamp or sequence number (should the protocol provide these). UDP doesn't guarantee that the packets will be received in the order they were sent.

Comment: I have to say that the described feature *would* be one I'd normally use, if it existed.  In situations where all the UDP packets in a series contain values for the same set of settings, often the most-recently-received packet is the only one the program cares about.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner, You made the mistake of assuming the most recently-received packet is the newest packet, which my answer warns against

Comment: @ikegame there are situations where that assumption is close enough to the truth to be useful.